# How can I show that $(-1,-1) \in \text{Argmax}\left[-\lambda_0(u_1 - 2u_2) +A(u_1-u_2)^2\right]$ implies $\lambda_0 = 0$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimal-control

> How can I show that $(-1,-1) \in \text{Argmax}\left[-\lambda_0(u_1 - 2u_2) +A(u_1-u_2)^2\right]$ implies $\lambda_0 = 0$?

The argmax is taken over $u_1$ and $u_2$ and  $A$ is costant.

The source is the following: Show that the optimal control of this problem is abnormal:
$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \max \int_0^1 (u_1-2u_2)dt \\
\dot{x} = (u_1-u_2)^2 \\
x(0)=x(1) = 0 \\
|u_1| \le 1 \\
|u_2| \le 1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Is A a negative const?

Comment: I do not know. $A$ is the multiplier of the control and it's given by $\dot{\lambda}(t) = 0$

Comment: Why a -1? Please add comments to specify what is wrong with this question.